# WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf

I am attempting to connect to an HTTPS endpoint in Java. Every method I have tried (more details below) ends up generating this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$proxy.methodXUZ(Unknown Source)
    at openconnector.ConnectorTest.main(ConnectorTest.java:83)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(Unknown Source)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

My code:

```
URL wsdlURL = Service.WSDL_LOCATION;
// use secured service
ServiceXYZ ss = new ServiceXYZ(wsdlURL, ServiceXYZ.SERVICE);
ServiceXYZPort port = ss.getServiceXYZPort();

BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
        
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://server.name/service/serviceXYZ.svc?wsdl");
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "pass");
        
        
System.out.println("Invoking Operation...");
java.lang.Boolean operation__return = port.operation();
System.out.println("operation.result=" + operation__return);
        
System.out.println(operation__return);
```

I already installed the certificate and tried to use *SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")*(got the same error).
I used apache-cxf to generate all wsdl clients.

Comment: Are there any proxy servers or firewalls involved? Are you successful with a http request outside of CXF?